# Abstract algebra: Associate elements of irreducible and prime elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove that (in an I.D.) an associate element of an irreducible element or a prime element respectively is itself always irreducible or prime respectively.

I found a similar post on the subject where they hade shown this for prime elements using the following proof:
p = prime in I.D.
u = unit in I.D.
a, b arbitrary elements of I.D.
Show that pu is also prime by contradiction:
Assume (pu) not a prime element
--> (pu) = (ab)
--> p=abu⁻¹ Contradiction!

But I don't understand why the last step gives a contradiction.

...and I don't know how to modify it for irreducible elements

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First off, that proof is for irreducibility, not primeness. Second, you need to assume $a,b$ are non-units (or, equivalently, non-associates of $p$). Third, it's a contradiction because $a$ and $bu^{-1}$ are non-units, which makes $p$ reducible.

As for primeness, you start by assuming completely analoguous things: this time $p$ is prime, $pu\mid ab$, and $pu\nmid a,b$. But if $pu\nmid a,b$, then we must have $p\nmid a,b$, and if $pu\mid ab$, we must have $p\mid ab$, contradicting that $p$ is prime.

As a final note, there is no need to make these proofs by contradiction. Just remove the assumption that $p$ is prime or irreducible, and you have a perfectly good proof by contrapositive. It feels cleaner to me that way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't understand your reasoning regarding proof by contrapositive, however. Should I simply put: r is reducible --> (ru)=(ab)-->r=(a)(bu⁻¹), neither of which is a unit. Can I simply assume that if (b) is not a unit, then neither is (bu⁻¹)? And is not the point of a an associated number that it is supposed to be the number itself times a unit?

Comment: @AnnikaS The resoning about contrapositive is just a side note, and not really important. I think it makes proofs look a bit cleaner, but it's not necessary for correctness. If it doesn't make sense to you, don't worry about it. And yes, if $b$ is not a unit, then no associate of $b$ is a unit either. Finally, the chain of implications that you have there should start with "$ru$ is reducible" instead of "$r$ is reducible" (that's what you're using when you write $ru = ab$), and when you reach "$r = (a)(bu^{-1})$, neither of which is a unit", then that by definition means that $r$ is reducible.